# Call lobibox.confirm from an ajax click event returns undefined before dialogbox is shown

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am stuck with this click call, which is returning undefined first then calls the function. I am using lobibox plugin

```
$('.action').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
//confirm option

if (agreed('Are you sure you want to increase the number?')=='yes')){

alert('go on');
}

});


function agreed(data){

                Lobibox.confirm({
                msg: data,
                callback: function ($this, type) {
                    return type;

                }
            });

      }
```

The agreed function is called but its input is not sent back. If i call it with alert(), it first results undefined then the dialogbox is shown.